# Memory error with Delphi 5 on 64 bit

Tags: delphi

I wrote a program in Delphi 5 whcih runs ok on my Windows 8 32 bit pc.   I find that running it on my Windows 7 64bit laptop eventually causes a  reallocmem error which does not happen on the 32 bit pc.  I inserted the following

```
MS.dwLength := SizeOf(MemoryStatus);
GlobalMemoryStatus(MS);
```

On the 32bit pc the size never changes but on the the 64bit laptop it fluctuates but over time gets smaller.   Is there some general mechanism in running 32bit Delphi 5 on a 64bit machine that makes this likely?

Comment: From the [GlobalMemoryStatus function documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):
*On computers with more than 4 GB of memory, the GlobalMemoryStatus function can return incorrect information, reporting a value of –1 to indicate an overflow. For this reason, applications should use the GlobalMemoryStatusEx function instead.*

Answer (score 2):

> Is there some general mechanism in running 32bit Delphi 5 on a 64bit machine that makes this likely?

If you have marked your application as `LARGEADDRESSAWARE` by modifying the PE flags post-build, then you may encounter problems because the Borland memory manager is not compatible with address >2GB.

If your application is not `LARGEADDRESSAWARE` then there is no obvious reason for it to fail on a 64 bit machine but not on a 32 bit machine. In which case the most plausible explanation is nothing more prosaic than your code having a defect that needs to be debugged.

Comment: Not marked as LARGEADDRESSAWARE.  My initial action was to check for any unfreed objects - manually as best I could and then with 'eyebol'.  It sounds like you are saying "code has a defect if it runs in 64bit but not if it runs in 32bit".

Comment: No. My guess is that code has a defect always. It just happens to manifest on one machine and not the other. The main point is that I think you are looking for a silver bullet solution. Configure the *** on 64 bit and the problem is fine. But that's not likely. My guess is that you need to look inside your code rather than outside it.

Comment: Thanks, you are probably right in your analysis so a return to reviewing my code is the next step.